# How to get currently login user with passport-jwt

Tags: express, passport-jwt

I implemented passport-jwt to authenticate user on protected route and also i want to check maybe the user login before creating first admin, please help me on how to do it.
this is my passport-jwt code that i have implemented

```
exports.getToken = function (user) {
  return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, { expiresIn: 3600 });
};

var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = config.secretKey;

exports.jwtPassport = passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    console.log("JWT payload: ", jwt_payload);
    User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload._id,  }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      } else if (user) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    });
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have authenticated a user and (s)he's logged in. Now, before creating an admin, you want to check if the currently logged in user hasn't expired or something else. Right ?

To do that:

1. You need to store JWT on the client-side so that whenever you call your API, you can attach the JWT in your request's authentication header. I say Authentication header because your `ExtractJWT` Strategy is `fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken`.
2. With this you can attach your token to subsequent API calls headers. You also need to implement a middleware on your server-side so that the controller can verify whether the JWT in the Authorization header is valid or invalid.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/api-authentication-with-json-web-tokensjwt-and-passport) is a good resource to understand the pipeline. Note that in this resource, they `fromUrlQueryParameter` as the extract strategy, but the concept is the same.